# Why there can be only one implementation of a typeclass for any given type parameter?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, typeclass, implicit

I'm reading the FP for Mortals book which has following line:

> There can only be one implementation of a typeclass for any given type parameter, a property known as *typeclass coherence*. Typeclasses look superficially similar to algebraic interfaces from the previous chapter, but algebras do not have to be coherent.

I do not understand this paragraph fully. Suppose we have following typeclass:

```scala
trait Ordering[T] {
  def compare(x: T, y: T): Int
}
```

I can create two implementations for the `Int` type like this:

```scala
val ord1: Ordering[Int] = new Ordering[Int] {
  def compare(x: Int, y: Int): Int =
    if (x > y) 1 else if (x == y) 0 else -1
}

val ord2: Ordering[Int] = new Ordering[Int] {
  def compare(x: Int, y: Int): Int =
    if (x > y) -1 else if (x == y) 0 else 1
}
```

What do authors mean when they say that typeclass can have only one implementation? It doesn't apply for instances of the typeclass as we can have multiple ones for the same type. To what it is applied? Also why ADTs are not coherent in that sense?

Comment: You can _(as you show)_, but you _"shouldn't"_. - Why? Because the mechanism used to use typeclasses usually relies in some kind of inference. Thus, if there are more than one implementation the compiler would not know which one to use, and if you have to explicitly specify which one you want, you are loosing some of the advantages of **typeclasses** - Now, for many typelcasses and for many types, there is usually only one instance, so not much of a problem. However, I agree there are cases where you would want a different one _(like a **Monoid** with multiplication instead of addition)_.

Comment: For those cases, each language present its workaround. Haskell has `newtypes` in scala you can always prioritize one over the other _(like defining one in the local scope)_ or being explicit over the one you want _(which somewhat contradict what I said in my previous comment, but I believe we all can agree is better to just being explicit only where it is strictly necessary, and being implicit on all the other cases)_.

Comment: @Dmytro Mitin's answer is correct so I don't want to add another answer. But I want to point out that the conceptual difference you're asking about comes from the fact that interface implementation is always chosen manually **by the programmer**. Typeclass implementation, however, is chosen  **by the compiler** (via the implicits mechanism explained in the said answer). So that's the difference.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. Now I see why implicits are important, when we create instances and demand them implcitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instances of a type class are defined as implicits.

```
implicit val ord1: Ordering[Int] = new Ordering[Int] {
  def compare(x: Int, y: Int): Int =
    if (x > y) 1 else if (x == y) 0 else -1
}

implicit val ord2: Ordering[Int] = new Ordering[Int] {
  def compare(x: Int, y: Int): Int =
    if (x > y) -1 else if (x == y) 0 else 1
}
```

If you ask `implicitly[Ordering[Int]]` you'll have

```
Error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both value ord1 in object App of type => App.Ordering[Int]
 and value ord2 in object App of type => App.Ordering[Int]
 match expected type App.Ordering[Int]
```